# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, процедуры

При создании процедуры:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_cp_all2
```AS 
begin 
    MERGE INTO ODS_MART.T$CP#ALL p
  --(date_execute, ID_CP, STATUS,PERIOD,QUANTITY_IN,QUANTITY_OUT,SOURCE_ID)   
USING ( 
    with cte as (
                  select date_l
                         ,source_id
                         ,cnt
                  from (
                  select trunc(oper_date) as date_l
                         ,1 as source_id
                         ,count(*) as cnt
                  from DWH_ARCH.T$SIRIUS#TRNS_DATA td
                  where 1=1
                        and oper_date >= to_date ('09.04.2021')
                       and oper_type  in (1,3,14)
                  group by trunc(oper_date)

                  union all

                  select trunc(oper_date) as date_l
                         ,2 as source_id
                         ,count(*)  as cnt
                  from DWH_ARCH.T$SIRIUS#TRNS_RNP_DATA
                  where 1=1
                        and oper_date >= to_date ('09.04.2021')
                        and oper_type  in (1,3,14)
                  group by trunc(oper_date)
                  )t
                 )```

select trunc(sysdate) as date_execute --???
       ,63 as ID_CP
       ,cc.period as PERIOD
       ,cc.source_id as SOURCE_ID
       ,TO_CHAR(sum(cc.quantity)) as QUANTITY_IN
       ,TO_CHAR(c.cnt) as QUANTITY_OUT
       ,case when sum(cc.quantity) - c.cnt = 0 then 'ОК' else 'Failed' end as STATUS
from ODS_MART.T$CHECK#CLOUD cc
left join cte c on c.date_l = cc.period and c.source_id = cc.source_id
group by cc.period
       ,cc.source_id
       ,c.cnt
     )p1
ON (p.id_cp = p1.id_cp and p.period = p1.period and p.source_id = p1.source_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET p.quantity_in = p1.quantity_in,
                p.quantity_out = p1.quantity_out,
                p.STATUS = p1.STATUS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (p.date_execute, p.ID_CP, p.STATUS,p.PERIOD,p.QUANTITY_IN,p.QUANTITY_OUT,p.SOURCE_ID)
VALUES (p1.date_execute, p1.ID_CP, p1.STATUS,p1.PERIOD,p1.QUANTITY_IN,p1.QUANTITY_OUT,p1.SOURCE_ID);
end;
````

Появляется сообщение о том, что процедуры создана с ошибкой. Из USER_ERRORS вижу две ошибки:

```
1   INSERT_INTO_CP_ALL2 PROCEDURE   1   4   26  PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges  ERROR   0
2   INSERT_INTO_CP_ALL2 PROCEDURE   2   4   5   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored   ERROR   0
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Отформатируйте текст пожалуйста

Comment: *insufficient privileges* - что именно непонятно в этих словах?

Comment: Т.е. ошибка Statement ignored возникает в следствие ошибки insufficient privileges?

Comment: _возникает в следствие ошибки insufficient privileges?_, да, это так. Получите или дайте привилегии, и всё  заработает.